# Typescript outfile with System.JS - Module instantiation error

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I'm using TypeScript to generate a single `outFile` that compiles my modules, loaded with SystemJS. When I follow the [documentation on loading bundles](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md#loading-bundles), as suggested by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049525/error-importing-typescript-compiled-modules-with-system-js), I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module instantiation did not call an anonymous or correctly named System.register.
    Instantiating http://localhost:50001/Content/js/app.js
    Loading app.js
        at vendor.js?v=c419d08…:4
```

Here is the setup script in my index.html file:

```
SystemJS.import("/Content/js/app.js").then(function (mod) {
    return SystemJS.import("admin/js/startup");
});
```

`app.js` looks like this:

```
System.register("shared/js/utilities", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    ...
});

System.register("admin/js/startup", ["shared/js/utilities"], function (exports_2, context_2) {
    ...
});
```

My `tsconfig.json`, if it helps:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "outFile": "app.js"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE:** I had been using `systemjs/dist/system-production.js`, because [the documentation](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#browser-production) states that modules already transpiled into the `System.register` format, which is done by TypeScript, can be loaded by the production loader. If I switch to using `systemjs/dist/system.js`, I do not get the errors. I still don't see how I am getting this error from the production loader if I'm already working with `System.register` formatted modules.

Comment: It looks like the error originates somewhere in `vendor.js` ...

Comment: @martin Yes, that contains the `systemjs/dist/system-production.js` file concatenated with other 3rd party library files. If I look around that part of the code in the dev tools, it's designed to throw that error if some object is missing a 'reference' property or something. I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Same problem here. system-production.js generates errors when the modules are bundled by the typescript compiler. There are no errors when loading system.js. Did you solve the issue?